# のせいで and お陰で nuance

Tags: word-choice

I'm having a hard time deciding which of the two fits better in the following sentence:

コロナウイルスのせいで家族と一緒にもっと時間を過ごしました。

I feel like using のせいで makes it sound like I'm accusing the coronavirus of making me spend more time with my family.
On the other hand, I feel like using のおかげで makes it sound like the coronavirus is a good thing, and I'm thankful for it.

Which is more proper to convey a positive outcome from a really bad situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's about how you feel about the outcome not the objectivity of it. So it's better to use お陰で here. It's literally saying, "Thanks to the Corona virus...", it doesn't imply that the Corona virus itself is objectively a good thing.

That aside, there is a Japanese expression for such cases, 不幸中の幸い. It's similar to the "silver lining of a dark cloud" expression in English. So you can phrase it as staying at home is a bad thing using せいで then say that the silver lining is that people were able to spend more time with their families.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didnt know that phrase. I also came across the option of use をきっかけに, is that a valid option? I think it is more nutral so it might fit

Comment: Yes, you can use that. There's also を機に with the same meaning.